# Get SigmaJS working

Tags: sigma.js

I am using `Windows 10` and want to use `SigmaJS` in my apache webserver. The webserver itself works.

I also have `node.js` installed and that works, too.

However, I don't know how to get `SigmaJS` running. I downloaded the zip file from the [website](http://sigmajs.org/) but don't know what I have to do to be able to use SigmaJS.

Answer (score 1):

SigmaJS is not a nodejs module, it's a front-end lib for your browser / html pages.

So you have to write your webpage that include SigmaJS and do what you want to do this Sigma.

Take a look at the `examples` directory into sigma'sources.

Cheers